# Ubuntu One Synchronize Folder not working

Tags: 12.10, ubuntu-one, pidgin, sync

I am trying to synchronize the Pidgin folder `.purple` in Ubuntu One.  However it is not synchronizing.  I was able to get this to work with a previous version of Ubuntu.  I am currently running `Ubuntu 12.10`.

[image]

The status of Ubuntu One appears to be fine:

```
$ u1sdtool --status
State: QUEUE_MANAGER
    connection: With User With Network
    description: processing the commands pool
    is_connected: True
    is_error: False
    is_online: True
    dqueues: IDLE
```

When selecting another folder to synchronize with Ubuntu One, after first selecting to synchronize, if you right click the folder again and select the Ubuntu One option it says "Stop Synchronizing This Folder".  But this is not the case with the `.purple` folder.  Is there are an issue with synchronizing hidden folders?

## Update

The strange thing is, this doesn't happen on my machine at work.  Although it still isn't properly syncing.

[image]

The Ubuntu One status is the same on my machine at work

```
$ u1sdtool --status
State: QUEUE_MANAGER
    connection: With User With Network
    description: processing the commands pool
    is_connected: True
    is_error: False
    is_online: True
    queues: IDLE
```

## Update 2

I have run the Ubuntu Control Panel Applet and saw that on my home machine the sync to `.purple` directory was not set up.  So I set that up, but it seems like I can only access the files in the `.purple` directory in the [Ubuntu One Service](https://one.ubuntu.com/dashboard/) and not locally on my machine.  I was expecting to be able to do things like grep the `logs` directory within the `.purple` directory but this no longer seems possible.  Is there something else that needs to be set up?

When you sync a directory that is located outside of the `Ubuntu One` directory, can you only access the files on the Ubuntu One website dashboard : [Ubuntu One Service](https://one.ubuntu.com/dashboard/)?

## Update 3

I can see the synced folders in the dashboard of [Ubuntu One Service](https://one.ubuntu.com/dashboard/) but can these folders be accessed in a terminal?

Comment: When you run "u1sdtool --status" do you get an error?

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and to fix it I did a few things. Lets hope it works for you as well.

First run the Ubuntu Control Panel Applet via Terminal, that way if there are any funnies you will see additional error messages in terminal over and above normal error messages fro the GUI app.

```
ubuntuone-control-panel-qt
```

From there add the folder manually by clicking the big add folder command at the bottom to see if that works, as the "add" via Nautilus doesn't.

I also manually logged into [Ubuntu One Service](https://one.ubuntu.com/dashboard/) and deleted some of my old computers syncs I wasn't using anymore.

Also check to see that the file syncs are getting through via the files tab on the web version of Ubuntu One.

I also logged out and rebooted to ensure the Sync would restart, although it seems your `u1sdtool --status` command worked whereas mine never didn't.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hey @Meer, when you sync a directory that is located outside of the Ubuntu One directory, can you only access the files on the Ubuntu One website dashboard : Ubuntu One Service?

Comment: Never tried, I sync my files via a cron job and encrypt the data using encfs so my data is safe. I would never rely on any sync that is not controlled by me. Hate things that happen automagically as it will always have flaws

Answer (score 1):

Any folder outside of `~/Ubuntu One` within your home directory that you choose to synchronize with the service will be synchronized fully, on any of your machines where it is subscribed. The folder is only subscribed by default on the machine which you enabled the synchronization from. All other machines will require you to subscribe to the folder using the `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt` application, or `u1sdtool` in a terminal.

If you have subscribed to the folder, and it is not synchronizing fully, it is possible that you may be encountering a bug, and should report it using `ubuntu-bug ubuntuone-client` or request support by filling the [Ubuntu One support contact](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/) form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't synchronise hidden folders (it's names start with .) - try to rename `.purple` as a eg. `Pidgin`, make symbolic link to this folder, name it .purple and try to sync `Pidgin`.
**In terminal:**
 1.`mv .purple Pidgin`
 2.`ln -s Pidgin .purple`
After that try to sync `Pidgin` folder.

Comment: I tried this and the sync didnt work.  It didnt let me add that `Pidgin` folder in the Ubuntu One Control Panel.